# Bazel build java demo: build ok but fail to run

Tags: java, build, jar, program-entry-point, bazel

I'm new to bazel and have this demo project:

(1)mkdir demo-project

(2)cd demo-project

(3)mkdir -p src/main/java/com/demo

(4)vi src/main/java/com/demo/DemoRunner.java

```
package com.demo;
public class DemoRunner {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Hello.hello();
    }
}
```

(5)vi src/main/java/com/demo/Hello.java

```
package com.demo;

public class Hello {
    public static void hello() {
        System.out.println("hello,world");
    }
}
```

(6)vi ~/demo-project/BUILD

```
java_binary(
    name = "hello",
    srcs = glob(["**/*.java"]),
    main_class = "com.demo.DemoRunner",
)
```

(7) bazel build //:hello

```
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
...........
Analyzing: target //:hello (2 packages loaded)
INFO: Analysed target //:hello (15 packages loaded).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //:hello up-to-date:
bazel-bin/hello.jar
bazel-bin/hello
INFO: Elapsed time: 60.505s, Critical Path: 1.24s
INFO: 1 process: 1 worker.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 6 total actions
```

Everything seems OK, but when I tried to

```
java bazel-bin/hello # Cannot find or load main class bazel-bin.hello
java -jar bazel-bin/hello.jar # Cannot find main list property in bazel-bin/hello.jar
```

Neither command is successful, as described above. So after bazel compile, how can I run the java executable?

Comment: In step 6, is that an extra comma after defining the `main_class` ? (is it needed? or is it just a typo on the question?)

Comment: I just tried to remove it, then same problem. Thanks.

Comment: you need to run `bazel-bin/hello` OR `java -cp bazel-bin/hello.jar com.demo.DemoRunner` , even you can run it using `bazel run //:hello`

Comment: Thanks Bhavik, that works for me

Comment: {bazel build ... }

Answer (score 1):

The Bazel command `run` can be used to run specified targets (see also comment from Bhavik):

```
bazel run //:hello
```

Answer (score 0):

`bazel build //...` & `bazel run //...` builds and executes everything. You can find the build specific to the targets from [here](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/guide.html#specifying-targets-to-build)

> //... All targets in packages in the workspace.