# bazel build java library doesn't generate any class file

Tags: java, class, build, classpath, bazel

I'm new to bazel and I have this demo-project and BUILD file:

```
package com.demo;

public class Hello {
    public static void hello() {
        System.out.println("hello,world");
    }
}
```

(1) mkdir src/main/java/com/demo, then I've got

DemoRunner.java:

```
package com.demo;
public class DemoRunner {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Hello.hello();
    }
}
```

Hello.java

```
package com.demo;

public class Hello {
    public static void hello() {
        System.out.println("hello,world");
    }
}
```

Then I run:

```
bazel build //:hello
bazel build //:HelloTest
```

It failed to find library:

```
java -classpath bazel-bin/hello.jar com.demo.DemoRunnerException in thread 
"main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/demo/Hello
    at com.demo.DemoRunner.main(DemoRunner.java:4)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.demo.Hello
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

I used "find" comand to search ".class" files, but didn't find any. I use "jar" file to check the hello.jar, I found only "class DemoRunner" is there but "class Hello" is missing:

```
jar tvf bazel-bin/hello.jar
  0 Fri Jan 01 00:00:00 CST 2010 META-INF/
 68 Fri Jan 01 00:00:00 CST 2010 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
  0 Fri Jan 01 00:00:00 CST 2010 com/
  0 Fri Jan 01 00:00:00 CST 2010 com/demo/
466 Fri Jan 01 00:00:02 CST 2010 com/demo/DemoRunner.class
```

So where did I get wrong, how could I built out my library file and make it run? But the way, where does bazel store all the class files that javac outputs?

Comment: You pasted the .java file instead of the BUILD file.

Comment: you can run `java -cp bazel-bin/hello.jar com.demo.DemoRunner` or `bazel run //:hello` or `bazel-bin/hello`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bazel build java demo: build ok but fail to run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54526458/bazel-build-java-demo-build-ok-but-fail-to-run)

Comment: Please show your BUILD file.

Comment: Did you try to run the run script under `bazel-bin/hello` instead of manually running the `java` command? FYI: Without adding your `BUILD` file contents nobody will be able to help you.